# During a git merge, how can I see which commit(s) are being merged

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm in the midst of a messy conflicted git merge operation.  For some reason, I forgot which branches or commits are currently being merged.  How can I see a list of commit(s) with which the current merge operation was initiated?

Comment: If you know which branch you are merging from, you can see the history of it's commits. You can use ```git log --no-merges branchMergingFrom ^branchToMergeTo```. This command will show you all the commits in branchMergingFrom which are not in branchToMergeTo.

Answer (score 6):

The `HEAD` revision points at the "left" (receiving) commit—the one which is checked out, while the `MERGE_HEAD` revision names the commit (or commits—in case of an "octopus merge") which is the "right side"—that is what is being integrated.

You can use the `MERGE_HEAD` with any Git commans which operates on revisions such as `git show`, `git log` etc, or pass it to `gitk`.

You can get more info from the [`gitrevisions(7)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) manual page (run `git help revisions`).

Answer (score 4):

To add to @kostix' answer :

- `git difftool -d HEAD...MERGE_HEAD` (3 dots) will give you a view of what is merged, similar to what Github or other platforms display in their Pull Request view ; this is also what `git` presents as "their" changes ;
- `git difftool -d MERGE_HEAD...HEAD` will show you what changed on the base branch ; `git` presents this as "our" changes ;
- `git log --oneline --graph --boundary HEAD...MERGE_HEAD` will show you all commits since the two branches forked.